# Android Studio Gradle: Ignored Annotations with GoogleServicesPlugin

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, build.gradle, google-play-services

I've searched through all of the answers I can find on stack overflow as well as on other similar sites, but the solutions there do not solve my problem.

I am trying to update my build tools on an old project from sdk 28 to sdk 31, to comply with the Google Play Store's security requirements, but every time I run `ionic cordova build android --stacktrace` I get the following result:

```
Dependency classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10' already exist
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter: Processed 69 Java source files in 1010ms
cordova-plugin-firebasex: Preparing Firebase on Android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/android-sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /opt/android-sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :app
WARNING:: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
For more information, see http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
WARNING:: API 'variant.getMappingFile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMappingFileProvider()'.
It will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getMappingFile(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask').
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'intermediateDir' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @OutputDirectory.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'intermediateDir'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'intermediateDir'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'packageNameXOR1' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'packageNameXOR1'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'packageNameXOR1'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'packageNameXOR2' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'packageNameXOR2'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'packageNameXOR2'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'quickstartFile' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @InputFile, @Optional.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'quickstartFile'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'quickstartFile'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'searchedLocation' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'searchedLocation'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'searchedLocation'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 14s
9 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 8 up-to-date
Command failed with exit code 1: /home/koseward/Desktop/iMATter/iMATterMobile/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /home/koseward/Desktop/iMATter/iMATterMobile/platforms/android/build.gradle
```

According to other answers, this seems to mean that I am using an old version of the `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10` plugin, but I can't find where that is being called.

#### What I've tried:

- Adding `ext{ GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION='4.3.10'}` to my global `allProjects` build.gradle. This didn't change the result
- Commenting the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` line in the local build.gradle. This changed the error message from `Cannot add extension with name 'googleServices', as there is an extension already registered with that name.` to the error shown above. This also was tried in a similar block in build.gradle that will be shown below.
- I added `<preference name="GradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion" value="4.3.14" />`  and `<preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="true" />` to config.xml. This seems to have standardize the version number, but does not fix the problem.
- I removed and re-added android with `ionic cordova platform remove android` and `ionic cordova platform add android` but this reset did not change the issues
- Changing the version of `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'` in both /platforms/android/build.gradle and /platforms/android/app/build.gradle. I am confused about this one because each time I try to build, it changes back or duplicates with the old version, but I cannot figure out where this is coming from.
- Ensuring the google-services.json has all necessary information. I have downloaded and redownloaded this file from firebase and it has not changed the outcome.

/platforms/android build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
    apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
    repositories repos
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:${cordovaConfig.AGP_VERSION}"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${cordovaConfig.KOTLIN_VERSION}"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    def hasRepositoriesGradle = file('repositories.gradle').exists()
    if (hasRepositoriesGradle) {
        apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
    } else {
        apply from: "${project.rootDir}/repositories.gradle"
    }

    repositories repos
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

/platforms/android/app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

if (cordovaConfig.IS_GRADLE_PLUGIN_KOTLIN_ENABLED) {
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

buildscript {
    apply from: '../CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'

    // Checks if the kotlin version format is valid.
    if(cordovaConfig.IS_GRADLE_PLUGIN_KOTLIN_ENABLED) {
        if(!cdvHelpers.isVersionValid(cordovaConfig.KOTLIN_VERSION)) {
            throw new GradleException("The defined Kotlin version (${cordovaConfig.KOTLIN_VERSION}) does not appear to be a valid version.")
        }
    }

    apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
    repositories repos

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:${cordovaConfig.AGP_VERSION}"

        if (cordovaConfig.IS_GRADLE_PLUGIN_KOTLIN_ENABLED) {
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${cordovaConfig.KOTLIN_VERSION}"
        }

        if(cordovaConfig.IS_GRADLE_PLUGIN_GOOGLE_SERVICES_ENABLED) {
            // Checks if the kotlin version format is valid.
            if(!cdvHelpers.isVersionValid(cordovaConfig.GRADLE_PLUGIN_GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION)) {
                throw new GradleException("The defined Google Services plugin version (${cordovaConfig.GRADLE_PLUGIN_GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION}) does not appear to be a valid version.")
            }

            // Create the Google Services classpath and set it.
            String gradlePluginGoogleServicesClassPath = "com.google.gms:google-services:${cordovaConfig.GRADLE_PLUGIN_GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION}"
            println "Adding classpath: ${gradlePluginGoogleServicesClassPath}"
            classpath gradlePluginGoogleServicesClassPath
        }
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    def hasRepositoriesGradle = file('repositories.gradle').exists()
    if (hasRepositoriesGradle) {
        apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
    } else {
        apply from: "${project.rootDir}/repositories.gradle"
    }

    repositories repos
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = cordovaConfig.GRADLE_VERSION
}

// Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
// Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
ext {
    apply from: '../CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'

    // Sets the versionCode to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
    }
    // Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
        cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
    }
    // Whether to append a 0 "abi digit" to versionCode when only a single APK is build
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit')) {
        cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for release signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for debug signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // Set by build.js script.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
        cdvBuildArch = null
    }

    // Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
    cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
}

// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
apply from: "../cordova-plugin-badge/iMATter-badge.gradle"
apply from: "../cordova-plugin-enable-multidex/iMATter-build.gradle"
apply from: "../cordova-plugin-firebasex/iMATter-build.gradle"
apply from: "../cordova-plugin-local-notification/iMATter-localnotification.gradle"
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

def hasBuildExtras1 = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras1) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}

def hasBuildExtras2 = file('../build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras2) {
    apply from: '../build-extras.gradle'
}

// Apply updates that might come from build-extra.
privateHelpers.applyCordovaConfigCustomization()

// Set property defaults after extension .gradle files.
if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('../debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = '../debug-signing.properties'
}
if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('../release-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = '../release-signing.properties'
}

// Cast to appropriate types.
ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
ext.cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit = cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit == null ? false : cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit.toBoolean();
ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)

def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
    def ret = 'assemble'
    if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
        def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
        ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
    }
    return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

// Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps {
    doLast {
        println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
        println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
        println('cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit=' + cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit)
        println('cdvSdkVersion=' + cdvSdkVersion)
        println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
        println('cdvMaxSdkVersion=' + cdvMaxSdkVersion)
        println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
        println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
        println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
        println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
        println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
        println('cdvAndroidXAppCompatVersion=' + cdvAndroidXAppCompatVersion)
        println('cdvAndroidXWebKitVersion=' + cdvAndroidXWebKitVersion)
        android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
            println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
        }
    }
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        minSdkVersion cordovaConfig.MIN_SDK_VERSION
        if (cordovaConfig.MAX_SDK_VERSION != null) {
            maxSdkVersion cordovaConfig.MAX_SDK_VERSION
        }
        targetSdkVersion cordovaConfig.SDK_VERSION
        compileSdkVersion cordovaConfig.SDK_VERSION
    }

    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false
    }

    buildToolsVersion cordovaConfig.BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    // This code exists for Crosswalk and other Native APIs.
    // By default, we multiply the existing version code in the
    // Android Manifest by 10 and add a number for each architecture.
    // If you are not using Crosswalk or SQLite, you can
    // ignore this chunk of code, and your version codes will be respected.

    if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        flavorDimensions "default"

        productFlavors {
            armeabi {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 1
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["armeabi"]
                }
            }
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["armeabi-v7a"]
                }
            }
            arm64 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 3
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["arm64-v8a"]
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["x86"]
                }
            }
            x86_64 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 5
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["x86_64"]
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit)) {
        // This provides compatibility to the default logic for versionCode before cordova-android 5.2.0
        defaultConfig {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = ""
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = ""
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }

    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

/*
 * WARNING: Cordova Lib and platform scripts do management inside of this code here,
 * if you are adding the dependencies manually, do so outside the comments, otherwise
 * the Cordova tools will overwrite them
 */


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${cordovaConfig.ANDROIDX_APP_COMPAT_VERSION}"

    if (cordovaConfig.IS_GRADLE_PLUGIN_KOTLIN_ENABLED) {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:${cordovaConfig.KOTLIN_VERSION}"
    }

    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.0"
    implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1"
    implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.1.1"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6"
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0"
    implementation "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }

    def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
    if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
        storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
    }
    if (!storeFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
    signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
    signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
    signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
    def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
    if (!storeType) {
        def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase()
        if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
            storeType = 'pkcs12'
        } else {
            storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
        }
    }
    signingConfig.storeType = storeType
}

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}

// if (cordovaConfig.IS_GRADLE_PLUGIN_GOOGLE_SERVICES_ENABLED) {
//     apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// }
```

I guess my main question is this: how do I ensure that I am using the right version of google-services?

I know this is old stuff, but I am hoping that by compiling all of the answers I have found and tried into one place, I can help someone else out who is trying to update an old app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, my solution was a reinstall. To solve, I simply did a fresh install of the project, on a new branch and started over. I also did a fresh install of my build tools, but I don't think this had any major effect on the result. I then changed the target SDK to 32, enabled android X, and updated some of my older Cordova plugins.